# Let $F_g: F(X) \to F(X)$ be a linear map such that $f \mapsto gf$. Compute the determinant of $F_g.$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $X =\{a,b,c\}$ and let $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function for which $g(a)=2,g(b)=4,g(c)=-1.$ Let $F_g: F(X) \to F(X)$ be a linear map such that $f \mapsto gf$ where $F(X)$ is the set of all functions $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$. Compute the determinant of $F_g.$

I have a slight problem when trying to express $F_g$ as a matrix. If I understood the problem correctly I have that $$F_g(f(a))= g(a)f(a) =2f(a) \\ F_g(f(b)) =g(b)f(b) = 4f(b) \\F_g(f(c)) =g(c)f(c) = -f(c)$$ but I would need to express this as a matrix in order to find the determinant. The fact that every linear transformation can be expressed as a matrix should apply here as well since $F_g$ is a linear map. How can I proceed with this?

Comment: As a technical point, you should have, e.g., $F_g(f)(a) = (gf)(a) = g(a)f(a)$, not $F_g(f(a))$ (which makes no sense, as the domain of $F_g$ isn't $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $F(x)$ is the set of all maps from $X$ to $\Bbb R$, then a basis of $F(x)$  will be $B=\{e_a,e_b,e_c\}$, where $e_x(y)$ (with $x,y,\in\{a,b,c\}$) is $1$ if $x=y$ and $0$ otherwise. Now, $F_g(e_a)=g\times e_a=2e_a$. You also have $F_g(e_b)=4e_b$ and $F_g(e_c)=-e_c$. So, the matrix of $F_g$ with respect to $B$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&4&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding where do the zeros come from for example for the first row or column?

Comment: From the fact that $F_g(e_a)=2e_2+0\times e_b+0\times e_c$.